# Non-ascii characters are not displayed in hyperref's pdftitle: bug in the 'unicode' option?

Tags: hyperref, pdftex, unicode, cyrillic

I'm trying to make `pdflatex` display non-ascii (cyrillic) characters in PDF metadata using `hyperref`'s `pdftitle` and `pdfauthor` options. Here is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % if uncomment, pdf search stops working
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{fancyhdr, doc, textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cmap} % to activate pdf search

\usepackage{hyperref}
\hypersetup {
    pdftitle={Название документа},
    pdfauthor={Автор документа},
}

\begin{document}
Hello, world! Привет, мир!
\end{document}
```

This does not work, cyrillic characters are just omitted. If I replace `\usepackage{hyperref}` to `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`, it starts working as expected. But what surprised me is that if I set `unicode=true` option in `\hypersetup` (and remove `unicode` from `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`), it does not work. Is it a bug or am I missing something?

Comment: Some `hyperref` options only have effect in the `\usepackage` command, see the `hyperref` manual. Could this be the case?

Comment: Perhaps my answer if off the mark as you already mentioned that with the unicode option it worked. Some years ago, even with a TeX source in iso-latin-1, in order to get the Latin letters such as éèùç to appear in the pdf info, I had to use `pdfencoding=pdfdoc` as option to `hyperref` so all my files have it. Much to my surprise through testing I discover tonight that it is not necessary after all for latin1 encode input to say anything to hyperref, so indeed I wonder why one would have to for utf8.

Comment: I think I should withdraw my answer as you had already found that passing some option to `hyperref` in the package loading solved the problem. Indeed it is surprising that cyrillic letters disappear whereas letters such as éèù, etc.. make their way (without any need for an option - much to my surprise!) into the info fields of the pdf.

Answer (score 1):

Add `pdfencoding=unicode` to the loading of `hyperref`

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[russian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
% \usepackage[T2A]{fontenc} % if uncomment, pdf search stops working
\usepackage{longtable}


\usepackage{fancyhdr, doc, textcomp}
\usepackage{ifpdf}
\usepackage{cmap} % to activate pdf search

\usepackage[pdfencoding=unicode]{hyperref}
\hypersetup {
    pdftitle={Название документа},%
    pdfauthor={Автор документа},%
}

\begin{document}
Hello, world! Привет, мир!
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I don't think you should withdraw it, though it resembles the solution I've found. I asked the question to share the solution and to learn why this is happening. BTW, I wonder what is the difference between `pdfencoding=unicode` and `unicode` options?

Comment: I am unable to fing `pdfencoding=unicode` or even `pdfencoding` documented in the `hyperref` documentation. I am just too old I guess... and use deprecated things. Perhaps `hyperref` salvaged my ignorant manners and decided to just do as if I had said `unicode`...