# How to use non-ascii characters in hyperref's pdftitle option?

Tags: hyperref, pdf, unicode, ascii

I'm trying to use non-ascii characters via hyperref's pdftitle option. I've read a [similar question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/79897/non-ascii-characters-are-not-displayed-in-hyperrefs-pdftitle-bug-in-the-unico), but its solution isn't working for me. I'm working on Overleaf and when I download the PDF, a new window opens up with the location where the file will be saved. But the suggested name for the document is "Matem_tica" instead of "Matemática".

[image]

I've failed trying all the following alternatives:

- `\usepackage[unicode]{hyperref}`
- `\hypersetup{...,unicode=true,...}`
- `\hypersetup{...,pdfencoding=pdfdoc,...}`
- `\hypersetup{...,pdfencoding=unicode,...}`
- `\hypersetup{...,pdfencoding=auto,...}`

Here is my document:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[sorting=none]{biblatex}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{epigraph}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[top=2cm, bottom=2.5cm, left=2.5cm, right=2.5cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hhline}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathabx}
\usepackage[framemethod=TikZ]{mdframed}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{csquotes}

\addbibresource{Referencias.bib}

\hypersetup{
    colorlinks  = true,
    pdftitle    = {Matemática}
}

\begin{document}
Hello!
\end{document}
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: With your provided MWE, I get compilation with `Matemática` listed as the Title in the PDF Property known as Description, when using Adobe Reader to open the file.

Comment: I should add that my compilation is local, using MikTeX, and not online via Overleaf.

Comment: Which texlive version do you use on overleaf?

Comment: I've checked the PDF properties on Adobe Reader and, indeed, the title is "Matemática", as it should be. But my description was actually misleading. Since I'm new to StackExchange, I'm not sure whether I should ask a new question or simply add a comment on the original one. The problem I'm actually facing is the following: even though Adobe Reader displays the correct title, when I click on the download button in Overleaf, as usual, a new window opens up with the location where the file will be saved. But the suggested name for the document is "Matem_tica".